# Port flash game to native android

Tags: android, game-engine

Alright here is the problem: the creators of a quite popular flash-based game have asked me to port their game to Android. They are not interested in any other platforms so we don't need to be worrying about iOS or PC. They want the best performance on just Android (I guess that's the point of porting a flash-based game. They could have just went with it)

They found Unity 'slow'. How would the performance (on android) of other engines compare? Are they expecting too much i.e. finding Unity slow? I am in favor of Unity since development is a little easier with more things being visual (I am not experienced as you might have guessed).

[This would be an example of the type of game I am to port](https://apps.facebook.com/master-blaster/index.php/?fb_source=canvasbookmark_recommended&count=0&code=AQBosHGoJl0iqEejJZl8n6QCe_5tHSa83SuA_59K8ueClqhGQ-a0WZs8G3C0e8hI01uXijUBb_bJBHql_6wHIjj4LCw_M9iFi4WqO6yPZCvJo-sOtGdmFrI3eIb5NSk4_tiO9tyvQ2a7iNSS9xQyn9NEmCFMWLhycp_NtwioCqmKWQlytGWbATm9TyvNhuWGQIE#_=_)

Thanks!

Edit: Some detail and link

Comment: I don't want to allow the facebook application to access my info :P  short description?  In any case, if it runs on Facebook, it should have no problems running in Unity.  Unless they built a proof of concept and it ran badly, they are just being ignorant.  It's your job as an engineer to tell them why the solution you selected is the best one.

Comment: well its a 3D cricket game with kind of basic graphics. models of cricketers with basic leg and arm movement. Some decision making in fielders catching the ball. (Hope this qualifies as description :S )

Comment: I have learned on the internet that ShiVa is faster. Maybe they want the best efficiency. Are there any benchmarks available for different engines?

Comment: It sounds like they want you to rewrite the entire app, not port it.  I'll expand my answer later, meeting for now.

Answer (score 1):

If it runs in flash, it should run in Unity.  Unity is written in C++, and should be much more efficient than Flash, IIRC.  Flex your developer muscles if possible and try to get them to listen to you.

Failing that, expand your question with a description of the game you're trying to port and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: see example game. its close enough :)